# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public class chap7p4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] heights = { 33, 45, 23, 43, 48, 32, 35, 46, 48, 39, 41, };
        printArray(heights);
        System.out.println("Average is " + findAverage(heights)); // this is where I get the error
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int eachNum : array) {
            System.out.println(eachNum + "  ");
        }
    }

    public static void findAverage(int[] array) {
        int average = 0;
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
            total = total + array[i];
        }
        average = total / array.length;
        System.out.println(average);

    }
}
```

I get this error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void"
```

Comment: Just change the return type of findAverage method to int. Right now, the return type is void.

Comment: You can also get this message for when combining a long string in System,out.println.. when you have two successive + .. For me it was tail end of one line, and beginning of the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAverage` has a void return type. Change the return type for the method to return an `int` value

```
public static int findAverage(int[] array) {
 ...
 return total / array.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method  `findAverage(heights)` has to return a value to be applicaable for the binary operator `+`, which takes two operants.

Answer (score 1):

Change return type of your `findAverage()` method,

i.e `void findAverage` to `int findAverage`

```
public static int findAverage(int[] array) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        total = total + array[i];
    }
    return total / array.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot make

`String` + `void`

`findAverage` method returns `void`

Answer (score 1):

`Return` type of `findAverage` method should not be void it should be integer for your code.
You should not print the value of average in same method as you are calling in main method.

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of "findAverage" function from void to int.

Answer (score 0):

Also here argument is of type int, and Operators like(*,+,..) won't work for argument type void and int so either change argument type or return type as mentioned above.